# npm only install minimal files without manual clean up

Tags: javascript, cordova, npm

For example, when you run:

```
npm install jquery
```

You get:

[image]

Is there a way to auto clean this so only the .min files show

Will manual deletion mess up `package.json` in node_modules?

I want it to look close to this:

[image]

I'd rather do this:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="node_modules/dist/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have no problem with manual 'clean up' but I don't want my links to get messed after I install from `package.json`

Comment: write your own package?

Comment: Its a general question because alot of packages come with extra things. JQuery is just an example

Comment: each npm package have it's own files. if you want that package to have different files - create your own package. there's no other way as i see it

Comment: you can post-process them by moving into some different directory after installation, using postinstall https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: Why..? When you `require` a package, it only includes the necessary files that are linked to the package

Comment: This is not for node.js, but for a front-end app

Comment: So I shouldn't do manual clean up and keep everything as is? Just didn't want to have all these unnecessary files from all the packages.

Comment: This is for a cordova app, so the extra files also increases he size of the app

Comment: doesn't cordova have some build step that will drop all unused files?

Comment: you can try `bower` instead, but i doubt it have only the min file

Comment: Does it @llamerr? Can you provide a link to this so I can stop worrying about this or either not use npm

Comment: I haven't used cordova - that's why I'm asking you. In my understanding you need to have some building step that will bundle your app into package, and I guess it should be integrated into cordova?

Comment: I'm not sure about cordova dropping unused files when building, but I'll look into it.

Comment: if it's not - you can always look at grunt/gulp and how they build things. they usually create `build` or `prod` directory that contains minified app, which you can then pass for cordova instead of you sources app. check for some generator like https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp. I'm not sure but if i recall correctly it had that `build` folder (or that was angular-fullstack generator?)

Comment: I would never include all the contents of my node_modules in the actual final release of an app. I would have my own dist folder, into which I move anything I actually need (you can write some grunt scripts to do all this for you automatically, if you use grunt). I think this is pretty common practice.

Comment: thanks! i'll look into grunt/gulp